# Node.js send and receive packets from any client

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, client-server, chromium-embedded

How a Node.js server can accept and connect to any requests even if they didn't come from clients that are connected directly to  server?

They only way is to create an API? I found a solution by importing the Node modules client-side  like `var http = require('http');` but are those safe and optimized?

I need it to communicate with a CEF application without implementing Node.js clientside.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people are using `http.createServer`. It is going to be fine for most situations. Use it with something like Express.js and you'll have a simple, easy solution.

Comment: createServer and listen shouldn't work similar here?

Comment: createServer works fine. Express helps with organizing routes. In other words, what should happen when someone requests '/home' or '/profile'. It also makes other things like dealing with errors like 404s easier.  You can do all that yourself if you want, but why?

Comment: I tried with socket.io-client but doesn't work ,I think I will use an iframe